# Tensorflow repeat array

Tags: tensorflow

I'm sorry, but I already searched for a long time and I didn't find the answer. I'm looking for Tensorflow function that repeats a rank 1 Tensor in an additional direction to generate a rank 2 tensor.
The reason is that I have two ranks 1 tensors and I want to calculate the difference between each element of the tensors.

Answer (score 1):

First for repeating the 1-D tensor, you can use [tf.tile](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/tile)

so for example if you wish to a tensor of shape [n] to be of shape [n, m], you can use it as follows:

```
output = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(input, axis=1), [1, m])
```

[tf.expand_dims](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/expand_dims) will add a new dimension of size 1, so the shape will change from [n] to [n, 1], then [tf.tile](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/tile) will repeat it [1, m] time so the shape will become [n*1, 1*m] = [n, m]

or if you wish the output to be shaped [m, n], you can do:

```
output = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(input, axis=0), [m, 1])
```

But I would like to add that to compute the difference between all elements in two 1D tensors, you don't need to repeat them, you can use broadcasting like this:

```
output = tf.expand_dims(input1, axis=1) - input2
```

so if `input1` is of shape [n] and `input2` is of shape [m], [tf.expand_dims](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/expand_dims) will add a dimension to `input1` so it will be of shape [n, 1] and during subtraction, Tensorflow will try to match their shapes using broadcasting. Since the rank of the 2nd operand (`input2`) is less than the rank of the 1st operand (the expanded `input1`), it will prepend 1's to the shape of 2nd operand till it matches the rank of the 1st operand, so the shapes of the operands will be [n, 1] and [1, m]. Then during the subtraction, the dimensions of size 1 will be broadcasted as if they match the corresponding dimension size in the other operand. So the result will be shaped as [n, m]. That is why in Tensorflow [1,2,3]+1 is similar to [1,2,3]+[1,1,1] both giving [2,3,4] as an output.

This solution is more memory efficient since no real repetition is done before the subtraction, broadcasting deals with the shape mismatch implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

there are several APIs to solve this problem:

1. [tf.repeat](https://tensorflow.google.cn/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/repeat): tf.repeat(input, repeats, axis=None, name=None). This API can be used after tf 1.15
2. [tf.keras.backend.repeat_elements](https://tensorflow.google.cn/versions/r1.14/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/repeat_elements?hl=en): tf.keras.backend.repeat_elements(x, rep, axis). "rep" should be Python integer, not Tensor.